# PHP Match array of words in string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array of words/phrase that i want to match in a string. If in the string i want to insert into a database table, but it must match the the whole string or phrase. For instance:

```
$string = "This is a Sample sting of information"; 
$words = array('This is', 'Test', 'sample', 'information', 'sting of information');
```

It would therefore match:
This is
sample
information
sting of information

Also not case sensitive.

I have got so far, but am stuck:

```
$string = "This is a Sample sting of information"; 
$words = array('This is', 'Test', 'sample', 'information', 'sting of information');        
foreach ($words as $word) {
        if (strstr($string,$word) !== false) {
            echo $word." - NO<br>";
        }
        else {
            echo $word." - YES<br>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Judging by all the typos I'm not hugely surprised it doesn't match: information > **informtaion**

Comment: your code is fine, u just need to change like `if(true){true}else{false}` in your example `if (strstr($string,$word) !== false) {
      echo $word." - YES<br>";
  }
  else {
      echo $word." - NO<br>";
  }`

Comment: `!== false` means TRUE not FALSE

Comment: you can use stristr for case insensitive chk my answer

Comment: @rax-shah: now u can check the updates friend

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are thinking `if (strstr($string,$word) !== false) {` this will return the False?

No, this will return TRUE, if keyword or phrase find.

**What you need here?**

*1 - You just need to change your `Status` as YES where you are using NO.*

*2 - Change your status as NO where you are using YES.*

*3 - For case insensitive value you can use [`stristr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php)*

**Modified Example:**

```
<?php
$string = "This is a Sample sting of information"; 
$words = array('This is', 'Test', 'sample', 'information', 'sting of informtaion');        

foreach ($words as $word) {
  var_dump(stristr($string,$word) !== false); // this will help you to understand, what is happening here.
  if (stristr($string,$word) !== false) {
      echo $word." - YES<br>";
  }
  else {
      echo $word." - NO<br>";
  }
}

?>
```

And also note that, as @CD001 said in comment you have a typo `information != informtaion`

Note that, [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.strstr.php) is a case sensitive function, for case insensitive you need to [`stristr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php);

Comment: Thanks, i still think its case sensitive though as Sample is not found

Comment: @user1315422: did u checked solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach ($words as $word) {
 if(stripos($string, $word) !== false) {
    echo "Yes"."<br>";
 }else{
   echo "no";
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Its not matching sample and its case sensitive i think.

Comment: @user1315422 updated the answer with stripos, it's working as you have described

Comment: dont know where is OP now